# How to change global slide transition effect duration in beamer?

Tags: beamer, transition

@diabonas presented a method to add global transition effect in beamer in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123003/34499) answer like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Add global transition effect \transfade
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade}{}

\begin{document}
\frame{\centering\Huge1}
\frame{\centering\Huge2}
\frame{\centering\Huge3}
\end{document}
```

Now how to define global transition duration. there is a command `\transduration{2}` for setting transition duration but when I use it like this:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade \transduration{1}}{}
```

it changes effects automatically from a slides to another. I tested different pdf viewer with different effects all the same.

The question is "How to change global transition duration?"

Comment: What do you want to set exactly with the `\transduration` command? It is to set the time between two transitions. If you use `\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade \transduration{1}}{}` this line in your preamble, when you will display your presentation in FullScreen, you will have each slide displayed 1 second. It is not the time of the effect of the transition you set with this command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\transduration` command has to be used to set the time you want a slide to be displayed for example if you place `\transduration{10}` after the `begin{frame}` command then this frame will be displayed 10 seconds when you will play your presentation in full screen (and maybe also not in full screen?). This command does not affect the time of the transition effect you define with `\transfade`.

If you want to modify the time of the transition effect you have to use the `duration` option of the `transfade` command

```
\addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{\transfade[duration=1]}{}
```

**Note**: The same goes for the `direction` option for the kind of transition using this option.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. I misunderstood `\transduration{1}` with `[duration=1]`. It solved my problem.

Comment: `[duration=1]` is working. But not with number less than 1 ! How it is possible to set fastest effect?

Comment: @sajjadG For me it works with 0.1 for example (I am using Adobe Reader). Which viewer are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux and I tested with evince and okular. evince handles some effects and okular handles some other!!! but none of them handles effect with less than 1 sec duration.

Comment: @sajjadG I am also using Linux but realised that the effects we are speaking about are designed for Adobe when I went through the problem related here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120839/31058 . If you want to use evince you will have to do without some features of the transitions.